# How to make gcs to take original file name as gcs object name?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Currently I have created a form, through which image files are uploaded to the corresponding google cloud storage bucket. But the stored image_name is different than the actual file name.. For ex, if I upload `foo.jpeg`, it turns into a filename of mixed upper and lowercase letters. But the content remains the same..

What I need to keep the uploaded file name as it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSON API to upload a file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/upload). It offers three options: simple upload, multipart upload, and resumable upload. In all options you need to specify the object name.

All options upload directly to the bucket - no need to go through your own server/instance.

Comment: I'm using an UploadHandler for uploading files into gcs. ie, I have given the url returned by `get_upload_urls` function in the POST form. How I modify the url with name of the object in which we are going to upload?

Comment: Do not use get_upload_urls. Use JSON API - it provides its own url where you add your object name. An additional benefit is that it saves you an extra call to your backend.